# Binds links to the returned results for jQuery Autocomplete UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code snippet is adapted from [a jQuery tutorial](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jqueryui.com/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];
      $("#tags").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ui-widget"> <label for="tags">Tags: </label> <input id="tags"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Which works well and generates options according to a given string.

[image]

Beside that, a [page](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/exercise) binds links to the returned results.

[image]

How do I implement this feature?

Comment: You should have a look at [Custom data and display](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) section

Comment: I'm not a jquery user. But could you loop over `availableTags` and wrap each string in an `<a>` tag, before passing to the jquery autocomplete function?

Comment: Or probably this: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select

Comment: a page binds links to the returned results. what does this actually mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `autoComplete` `select` feature which will let you binds links to the returned results for autocomplete.

You also need to save your data like this below. So the URL of autocomplete words can be opened when clicked on the selection.

To open the search results we can use `window.open` this mean the url will be opened in new tab.

> **Working Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/09dtrk7L/2/

Run snippet below (**Note:** The url will not open *here* so you need to try the Demo link above. `window.open` is blocked by the snippet.)

```js
$(function() {

  //Your autocomplete data
  var availableTags = [{
      value: "Google",
      url: "http://www.google.com/",
      label: "Google"
    },
    {
      value: "Example website",
      url: "http://www.google.com/",
      label: "Example website"
    },

  ];

  //Autocomplete
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,

    //Open window on select
    select: function(event, data) {
      window.open(data.item.url, '_blank');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-menu-item-wrapper {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//jqueryui.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jqueryui.com/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ui-widget"> <label for="tags">Tags: </label> <input id="tags"> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe we're almost achieve it. When I click the returned options, Chrome opens a new tab with URL `http://127.0.0.1:5500/www.google.com`. Do I need some server configuration?

Comment: @RobertH I have updated my answer and the DEMO now. I did not added url as `http://www.google.com/` thats why it was loading like that. You have to add urls like `http://example.com` so window.open works normally.