# "value" vs. "label" in jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question comes from [Binds links to the returned results for jQuery Autocomplete UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63089431/13989140), which uses both `value` and `label` for autocompletion with jQuery.

In fact, just `value` could do the job.

```
  var availableTags = [{
      value: "Merriam-Webster",
      url: "http://www.learnersdictionary.com/"
    },
    {
      value: "Cambridge Dictionary",
      url: "https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/"
    }
  ];
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/90d18m2g/5/)

When should I use which?

I tried go through the [source code of autocomplete.js](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js) but didn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label is what is displayed to the user and the value is what the input field's value is set to when that element is chosen.

According to the [API documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source):

> The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the label.